# List of lists into dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've a list of lists something like this

```
[['a',20],['b',30],['c',40],['d',50]]
```

I've to convert it into a dict like this

```
{'a':20,'b':30,'c':40,'d':50}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a = [['a',20],['b',30],['c',40],['d',50]]
>>> b = dict(a)
>>> print b
{'a': 20, 'c': 40, 'b': 30, 'd': 50}
```